# pod update/install fails at Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.24)

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

When I run pod install or pod update in my flutter project, it fails at Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.24). And it prints this error message,

[!] Error installing BoringSSL-GRPC
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/google/boringssl.git /var/folders/mv/09sm2s1j0dd8dswfdcjg7vz00000gn/T/d20240208-44161-pig7ei --template=

Cloning into '/var/folders/mv/09sm2s1j0dd8dswfdcjg7vz00000gn/T/d20240208-44161-pig7ei'...
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
error: 4882 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

Any help on how to resolve this?

This are the solutions I applied but all fails

1. git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
2. git config --global core.compression 0
3. git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by applying the following

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 100000M
```

Even though I increased http.postBuffer little by little, gRPC-Core installation failed in addition to BoringSSL-GRPC, and I finally raised it to 100000M.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because of connectivity issue.

[image]I have been trying for days but I was getting the same error. Today I changed my internet connection, I run "pod install" it gave errors on different package installation but I kept trying and the installation was successful. The solution is changing your internet connectivity and if you are getting different error messages on each try, keep trying or running "Pod install", the installation will be completed,

Please see the attached image and analyse how the error message is changing with each try.

Comment: What do you mean by "changing your internet connectivity?" You mean switch from wi-fi to tethered ethernet, or something like that?

Comment: What I mean is, try it on a faster internet. doesn't matter whether you are using a wifi or ethernet.

Comment: Well, if I had such an option at home I surely would. My internet speed is the only speed available; I literally cannot control it. "try on a faster internet" isn't really an option for a vast majority of people, I think?

Comment: try when there are less users on the network. I had the same situation as you, I tried at night after 1 am, and it worked.